# Series and concavity

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-analysis

If $u(x)$ is strictly concave, can I say:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\cdot u(n) < \infty.
$$

I am having trouble finding counterexamples.

Thanks.

Comment: This is odd: first, is that an *infinite* series or what? Second, what does "concave" mean for you: convex upwards (like $\;x^2\;$) or downwards (like $\;-x^2\;$)?. Third, whatever it means, you can take something like $\;\frac1{x^2}\;$ or like $\;\frac1{\sqrt x}\;$ (depending on the case) and thus that sum can't possibly be negative

Comment: I mean concave as in convex downwards. The sum above is in fact an infinite series; I thought it would be clear from context. Could not understand your third point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $u$ is strictly concave, for $n \ge 1$ we have
$$u(n) \le (u(1) - u(0))n + u(0),$$
so that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n-1} u(n) \le u(0) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n-1} ((u(1) - u(0))n + u(0)) < +\infty.$$